# Ansible regex_search with list

Tags: regex, ansible

I am facing issues in applying regex_search on ansible list. Below is my use case:

I have a list as shown below. Now I want to extract workflowinstanceid parameters from each index of list and store it in a separate list. I am trying to achieve this using regex_search. Can anyone please help me out?

```
    "final_dr_logs": [
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "changed": true,
            "stdout": "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 CLIENT22 workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160515,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "delta": "0:00:00.273316",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 CLIENT22  workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160515"
            ],
            "_ansible_item_label": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "end": "2020-12-10 06:23:36.680901",
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "stderr": "",
            "rc": 0,
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "changed": true,
            "stdout": "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 CLIENT22 workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160516,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "delta": "0:00:00.273316",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 ES194CLIENT22  workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160516"
            ],
            "_ansible_item_label": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "end": "2020-12-10 06:23:36.680901",
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "stderr": "",
            "rc": 0,
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "changed": true,
            "stdout": "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 ES194CLIENT22 workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160517,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "delta": "0:00:00.273316",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 ES194CLIENT22  workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160517"
            ],
            "_ansible_item_label": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "end": "2020-12-10 06:23:36.680901",
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": "16b70d66-493a-4cdb-98fd-eb5de081491d ",
            "stderr": "",
            "rc": 0,
        }]
```

**Here's my code:**

```
- name: Extract workflow instance IDs
   para_wfId: "{{ item | regex_search(regexp, '\\1') | first }}"
  vars:
   regexp: 'workflowinstanceid=jbpm\$(.*?),'
  with_items:
   - "{{ final_dr_logs }}"
  register: wfid
```

**Error that I am getting:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

new_list=[160515,160516,160517]

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax (specifically your second task line is not indented correctly). Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You should also read through the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) to learn the basic concepts and syntax. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting.

Comment: Moreover, I don't know any module named `para_wfId` and nothing else in you task looks like a module name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to extract workflowinstanceid parameters from each index of list and store it in a separate list.

that is what the jinja2 [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) is for; they even use the exact construct you're asking about in  [the manual page for `regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) although I think `findall` with a capture group and `first` easier to read than `regex_replace`

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ final_dr_logs
        | map(attribute="stdout")
        | map("regex_findall", "workflowinstanceid=(.+)$")
        | map("first")
        | list }}
    vars:
      "final_dr_logs": [
        {
            "stdout": "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 CLIENT22 workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160515"
        },
        {
            "stdout": "[defaultAsyncAction1] - 12/10/2020 02:56:36 CLIENT22 workflowinstanceid=jbpm$160516"
        }
      ]
```

produces

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "jbpm$160515",
        "jbpm$160516"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your response helped me to resolve my problem.